# Can a BIVS visa holder visit Amsterdam for 2 days?

Tags: schengen, london, ireland, amsterdam

I am visiting Ireland and London the next 9 days on a BIVS visa and I want to stay in Amsterdam for a very short time, 2 days only. Can I get a visa on the spot for Amsterdam for 2 days? I don't have enough days left to get a Schengen visa from India.

Answer (score 5):

You need a Schengen visa.

The BIVS visa is only good for visiting the UK and Ireland.

Comment: Do we have any other way to get the short stay in Amsterdam, when i will be there in London any how?

Comment: No, you have to get a Schengen visa.

Comment: @Ankush If you're fine with a two-day short stay in Schiphol, perhaps (but probably not); otherwise, no.

Answer (score 4):

> can I get the visa on the spot for Amsterdam

Schengen regulations require that you apply for the visa in your place of residence.  You will generally not be able to get it "on the spot," nor in London.

From the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412), article 6(1):

> Article 6
>
> Consular territorial competence
>
> 1. An application shall be examined and decided on by the consulate of the competent Member State in whose jurisdiction the applicant legally resides.

The consulate can make an exception for a compelling case, but your question does not give the impression that your case is compelling.  The [guidance](https://www.udiregelverk.no/PageFiles/2788/Visa_Handbook_I_09.07.2014.pdf) suggests that such cases should involve family illness, an unavoidable change in plans, or an absence from your residence that is so long that you are unable to apply there within the three-month period for submitting applications.